# Detect scrolling effects for AppBarLayout & NestedScrollView

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, nestedscrollview

I have this layout (code is at the bottom) which contains a CollapsingToolBarLayout at the top and a NestedScrollView at the bottom.

When I scroll up, the collapsing toolbar will start to collapse, then the scroll view will scroll up with the collapsing toolbar at first and then goes behind the collapsed tool bar.

I want to have some animations (image slides left when scrolling up and slides back when scrolling down) in the collapsing toolbar. The issue now is: **sometimes, when I scroll up, the image doesn't slide left. When it slid left, and I scroll down, it doesn't slide back.**

I trigger these animations through `onOffsetChanged` for the `AppBarLayout` and `OnTouchListener` for the `NestedScrollView`.

```
// People image slide left when user scrolls up on the scroll view
mScrollView.setOnTouchListener(scrollViewTouchListener);


// People image slide back when app bar is almost expanded
mAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(appBarOffsetChangedListener);

// OnOffsetChangedListener for the AppBarLayout
    private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener appBarOffsetChangedListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {

    // If the app bar is almost expanded and people image slided left, make it slide back
    if ((offset > -20 || offset == 0) && mPeopleSlidedLeft) {
        mPeopleImage.animate().setDuration(animationTime)
                .translationX(originalPeoplePosition[0]);
        mPeopleSlidedLeft = false;
    }
}
};

// Touch listener for the scroll view
private View.OnTouchListener scrollViewTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float y = event.getY();

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

        // if user scrolls up and people image hasn't slided left,
        if (dy < -1 && mPeopleSlidedLeft == false) {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            int xDest = dm.widthPixels / 2;
            xDest += mPeopleImage.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            mPeopleImage.animate().setDuration(animationTime)
                    .translationX(originalPeoplePosition[0] - xDest);
        }
    }

    mPeopleSlidedLeft = true;
    mPreviousY = y;
    return false;
}
};
```

Just note that the scrollview's setOnScrollChangeListener won't work as it's not triggered when the toolbar is collapsing.

A simplified version of the layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_margin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="120dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/active_inactive_time_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_navigation_bar_offset" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can someone please have a look? I will really appreciate it!

Comment: I had the same exact problem, it only occurs if you scroll fast enough. looks like the solution is to write a custom `Behavior` look at `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.Behavior` for an example, you can read these too [1](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26) and [2](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo Thanks. In my case, the animations sometimes didn't start when I scroll at a normal speed. They normally don't happen when I scroll fast. I'll check out those links and see if I can figure out a solution

Comment: Can you post a gif with outlined behavior?

Comment: @azizbekian Hi. I added 2 images. See if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a touch listener on the `NestedScrollView`, if I understand correctly you want there to be 2 states:

1. Toolbar is expanded and people image is visible
2. Toolbar is collapsed and people image is hidden

And the transition between these 2 states should be to slide the people image off the left of the screen?

This should be achievable with the `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` alone, and you can use the change of offset to "animate" the view moving instead of setting up trigger points which can result in a much smoother implementation.

Something like:

```
private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener appBarOffsetChangedListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        float fraction = ((float) Math.abs(verticalOffset)) / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        int peopleRange = mPeopleImage.getRight();
        mPeopleImage.setTranslationX(fraction * peopleRange * -1);
    }
};
```

I've added some configuration of the timing and speed of the slid. In this case it waits until the header is collapsed 25% before sliding and the image moves left twice as fast. You could play with these numbers to get what you're looking for.

```
private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener appBarOffsetChangedListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        float fraction = ((float) Math.abs(verticalOffset)) / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        int peopleRange = mPeopleImage.getRight();
        float delay = 0.25f;
        float speed = 2f;
        fraction = Math.max(fraction - delay, 0f) * speed;
        mPeopleImage.setTranslationX(fraction * peopleRange * -1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @darnmason. Thanks for the answer. I'd like to have the image slide to the left when Toolbar is collapsed ~3% ish when user scrolls up. When it is expanded again, the image slides back. I have tried OnOffsetChangedListener. It was slow. Also, I use it to move the image back to the screen now. Sometimes, it fails. The image doesn't back.

Comment: I've added another example to show how you can tweak the behaviour of the slide

Comment: This works much better than before. I can tweak it a bit to make it perfect. The way you do the Translation is something new to me. Actually, there is a Scale animation for wave image. I'll try to figure this out myself. Otherwise, I'll ask you here. Thanks again.